# Git pull: без принудительного удаления файлов

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Всем привет! Ребята, кто-то может подсказать как реализовать следующий кейс:
в локальном репозитории я добавил в файл .gitignore директорию `wp-content/plugins` после чего выполняю `git rm wp-content/plugins --cached` (дабы очистить файлы которые уже были в индексе, без их физического удаления). Делаю пуш, подтягиваю изменения в другом проекте. Во время пула удаляются все файлы из `git rm wp-content/plugin` (что мне не нужно, необходимо, чтобы файлы остались). Кто-то может подсказать как сделать пул без удаления файлов? Возможно существует специальный флаг?

Comment: «Во время пула удаляются все файлы из...» - это во второй рабочей копии, или в той, где делали `git rm`?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, во второй

Comment: [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8)?

Answer (score 3):

Насколько мне известно, на данный момент "красиво" это не сделать. Нужно в каждой рабочей копии (кроме той, где выполнен `git rm`) вручную сделать бэкап удаляемых файлов (например, просто скопировав во временную директорию), затем выполнить `git pull`, и следом восстановить файлы вручную.